# How to 301 Redirect with a % in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So I just made a list of 423 301 Redirects with a normal .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /blog-articles/129/Bad_Economy_Thank_You%2C_I_Didnt_Know.html /2010/05/bad-economy-thank-you-i-didnt-know-2/
```

My issue though is probably 50 of the URLs have a `%` in them and they don't redirect anywhere. I couldn't see any rewrite or regular expressions that looked to work. This seems to be somewhat of an anomaly for me. Can anyone please point me in the right direct on how to redirects URLs that have a `%` in them like the URL below.

```
/blog-articles/129/Bad_Economy_Thank_You%2C_I_Didnt_Know.html
```

Thank you advanced. (i'm starting to pull my hair out)

Comment: % should be interpreted as the start of a urlencoded character, which must be valid. Have you tried removing the character to see if the problem is exactly the %?

Comment: Try using the B flag in mod_rewrite.

Comment: Also try enclosing it in quotes. `"/blog-articles/129/Bad_Economy_Thank_You%2C_I_Didnt_Know.html"` if you stay with Redirect

Comment: @Zerquix18 I need the % in the URL because that is how the old sites CMS had it work.

The title of that article was Bad Economy Thank You, I Didnt Know so it turned the comma into the %2C which has to be in the URL to make the redirect work.

Comment: @PanamaJack I just tried this and it didn't work! :/

You had my hopes up for a second.

Answer (score 0):

@Zerquix18 pointed me in the correct direction!

The % was really apart of %2C which is a ",". So I went through the whole redirect list and changed any urlencoded characters to the actual character by referencing http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

It's always funny how after you ask a question it's way easier to solved!

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `\x2C` for `%2C` in your pattern. Try this rule:

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/blog-articles/129/Bad_Economy_Thank_You\x2C_I_Didnt_Know\.html /2010/05/bad-economy-thank-you-i-didnt-know-2/
```